# Binding a combo box vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin8

I'am trying to convert vaadin 7 code to vaadin 8 code Instead of using BeanFieldGroup vaadin 8 docs uses Binder instead to bind form fields to a class. This does not seem to work for combo box's.

I've looked for a way to use converter which does not seem to be available for combo box. As used in binding data to form in the vaadin documentation  [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html)

For one field the converter worked:

```
binder.forField(age).withConverter(
                    new 
StringToIntegerConverter("Must enter a number")).bind(
                    Student::getAge, 
Student::setAge);
```

But for a combo box I'am unsure how this will work.

```
ComboBox<String> gender = new ComboBox<String>("Gender");

Binder binder = new Binder<Student>(Student.class);

binder.bind(gender, Student::getGender, Student::setGender);
```

Which I know will not work is there a way to write a converter for a combo box or should another way be used altogether.

Comment: `Which I know will not work` - why not? looks good to me. Did you set items for the ComboBox? There should never be a need for a Converter on a ComboBox - You can always add an `ItemLabelGenerator` where you can define the conversion from the original type to how it should be displayed (default is toString, but you could convert it to Vaadin Components for example. see how it is done in the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-components))

Comment: I got a error message The method bind(HasValue, ValueProvider, Setter) in the type Binder is not applicable for the arguments (ComboBox<String>, Student::getGender, Student::setGender) but when I tried to replicate the error no error was there. But using bindInstanceFields was easier though.

Comment: is gender actually an Enum or is it a String in your student object? using bindInstanceFields can be easier but IIRC then it only works for very basic bindings - no converters, validators, nullRepresentations, or readOnly (no setter) can be set, and you can't bind nested fields of the Student object. it basically applies `binder.forField(field).bind("propertyName")` for each HasValue-component in your view

Comment: It is an Enum in a string utils with a toString method

Comment: aha! you should define your ComboBox as `ComboBox<Gender>` then!

Comment: Thanks this must have been the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that the `gender` field in your `Student` object is actually an Enum and not a String.

Your mistake was that you defined the ComboBox with type String instead of your Gender enum.

Assuming your gender enum class is called `Gender`, this will work:

```
ComboBox<Gender> gender = new ComboBox<Gender>("Gender");
Binder<Student> binder = new Binder<Student>(Student.class);
binder.bind(gender, Student::getGender, Student::setGender);
```

You can add an `ItemLabelGenerator` to the ComboBox to define how the selected Gender value should be displayed (and `Renderer`, which will control how the items in the dropdown will look). By default it will use `toString()` of the class, both for itemLabelGenerator and for renderer. But you could use the Renderer to build Vaadin Components for example if you want. see how it is done in the [ComboBox documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box#custom-item-presentation)).

The selected value can only be displayed as a String. If you want to let it be displayed as a Vaadin Component instead, you could use a `Select` component instead. [Select documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/select#custom-item-presentation).

Comment: Vaadin 17 and still works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in vaadin 8 uses bindInstanceFields to bind form data to a class.

```
Binder binder = new Binder<Student>(Student.class);

binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
binder.readBean(student);
```